# how to find exact match with cs fine e command with 'cscope'

Tags: regex, cscope

Im trying to find an exact match of a word with **csope** .

I tried (inside vim)

```
cs find e \bmyword\b
cs find e ^myword$
```

and both not working .

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Does you vim has `cscope module`? `vim --version|grep cscope`
2. Did you prepare the cscope file? check [this link](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html)

Comment: Ali Nikneshan - the answer is yes for both question. Im navagating the kernel with vim+cscope and all commands working great . find t,find g, find c etc